# Swift 5 SQLite to TableView

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, uitableview

I just want to populate Tableview from SQLite database. your help is very appreciated.
I believe the issue is easy to solve but I couldn't do that because a lack of experience in Swift development. Here are the code I have been using.

I think the missing part is:

- Create new array
- append sqlite data to array

So, the question is: How to append many columns from database to array and show them in Table-view. Thanks:)

**Swift 5**

```
import UIKit
import SQLite

class MyClass1: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    
    
    var db: OpaquePointer?
    
    var names = [
        "Sam",
        "Mark",
        "Kia",
        "John"
    ]
    var filteredData : [String]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        filteredData = names
        
        // connect to database
        let fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("myDB.db", isDirectory: false)

        //opening the database
        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
            print("error opening database")
        }

        
        let queryString = "SELECT * FROM people"
        
        var stmt:OpaquePointer?
        
        if sqlite3_prepare(db, queryString, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }
        
        while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
            let id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0)
            let name = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
            print("id:\(id) name:\(name)")
        }
        
        self.tableview.reloadData()
        
        
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You clicked me! at \(indexPath.row)")
    }

    // MARK: search bar config
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        print("search word entered!")
        
        filteredData = []
        
        if searchText == "" {
            filteredData = names
        } else {
        
            for name in names {
                if name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                    filteredData.append(name)
                }
            }
        }
        
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
    
    // called when keyboard search button pressed
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, why aren't you using `append` to add the data from your sql query? `names.append(name)` in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for your comment, This is my question, How to append many columns to one array and show them in Table-view. Thanks:)

Comment: Ok, I got it. See my answer below.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for your fast response, I really have hard time to implement your idea especially in `cell.textLabel?.text= ?????` and also how to modify filteredData array to match the people array. if you could re-post the whole controller it would be great!. Thanks in advance

Comment: No I will not rewrite the whole view controller class for you, this is not what stackoverflow is for and you should respect that. I have added an example to my answer for how the filtering could be done but my advice for you would be to ignore the searching (filteredArray and searchBar) for now and concentrate on making the table view work with the new People struct array, once that is done you can add the searching functionality back.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new custom type to hold the data from the sql table

```
struct People {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

in your view controller add an array as a class property

```
var people: [People] = []
```

and then fill that array with the result of the sql query

```
while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
    let id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0)
    let name = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1))
    people.append(People(id: id, name: name))
}
```

You will need to let your filteredData array hold People objects as well and the filtering needs to be changed.

```
for person in people {
    if person.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
        filteredData.append(person)
    }
}
```